# string.find not returning nil when searching for "."

Tags: string, lua, find

There isn't very much explaining to do with this question, so if I type this into the Lua Interpreter (modified from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)):

```
print(tostring(string.find("Hello Lua user", "banana")))
```

The returned output is `nil`, as expected. But, if I try the same thing with "." instead of "banana", like this:

```
print(tostring(string.find("Hello Lua user", ".")))
```

I get `1`, why is this? And is there any way I can detect whether there are dots in a string? (In case it's relevant, I need to know so I can detect whether a directory is a file or a folder (Yes, I know you can have dots in folders/no dots in files on Linux))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` uses Lua's pattern matching unless you tell it not to. `.` is a [character class](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) meaning "any character". If you want to find an actual period, you need to either:

1. Escape the period: `%.`.
2. [Tell `find` to not using pattern matching.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.find)

This is all [in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1), which is probably where you should start with these kinds of questions.

Comment: Ah, I never new "." would mean something different in Lua, I guess it's similar to "\" in C++

Comment: It's not like "\\". That's a escape character for creating certain character values in a string literal. This is a particular *interpretation* of a particular character in library routine.